# xcode 4.2.1 - storyboard - Moving from different view using modal and having Tab bar visible

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, storyboard

In xcode storyboard, I have created a Tab Bar Controller that goes to 4 different tabs. One of the tabs is the main menu that has the same links available at the Tab bar. When I use the tab bar to move to the tabs, I do have the tab bar visible. But when I use the main menu links it goes fine to the different views but I lose the tab bar. How can I go from view to other view without losing the tab bar.

I have no header files in my project everything is done through storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class implementation file for the view that you are using as a menu, in  it you need to create a function that is called when you press the buttons.  In those functions, you should call the following:

```
 // Change 0 to the tab index that you want to display.
 [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

or

```
 // Change theAppropriateViewController to the view controller that you want to display.
 [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:theAppropriateViewController];
```